# Resource.Getobject or Image.Fromfile

Tags: c#, image, resources

Hi I'm new here I'm trying to display an image that is in the same folder as the sln  on a picturebox. I accidently put the image in resources. And I'm just wondering if there is a difference in performance between:

```
Bitmap r = (Bitmap) MyProject.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Mybmp");
```

and

```
Bitmap r = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile("Mybmp.bmp")
```

or not

Comment: Most likely the performance gain (if any) is neglectable. Good thing with using it as an embedded resource is that you don't need to include the image when deploying.

Comment: Using a resource is fastest, you eliminate the cost of the OS having to locate the file.  It is not for free, a resource permanently occupies address space in the process, you'll run out of memory quicker.  Practically that only matters if the bitmap is large and you force your program to run in 32-bit mode.